# In meteor, are successive operations on the server synchronous?

Tags: meteor

If, as part of a single Meteor.call, I make two calls to the database on the server, will these happen synchronously or do I need to use a callback?

```
Meteor.methods({
    reset: function(id) {
        Players.remove(_id:id);
        // Will the remove definitely have finished before the find?
        Players.find();
        ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> In Meteor, your server code runs in a single thread per request, not in the asynchronous callback style typical of Node. We find the linear execution model a better fit for the typical server code in a Meteor application.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs on docs.meteor.com/#remove
you can find this :

> Blockquote
>   On the server, if you don't provide a callback, then remove blocks until the database acknowledges the write and then returns the number of removed documents, or throws an exception if something went wrong. If you do provide a callback, remove returns immediately. Once the remove completes, the callback is called with a single error argument in the case of failure, or a second argument indicating the number of removed documents if the remove was successful.
>
> Blockquote
>   On the client, remove never blocks. If you do not provide a callback and the remove fails on the server, then Meteor will log a warning to the console. If you provide a callback, Meteor will call that function with an error argument if there was an error, or a second argument indicating the number of removed documents if the remove was successful.

So on server side you choose if you want it to run in a sync or async way, it depends if you send a callback or not.